# Kivy: Updating label text will schedule_once

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to work with Clock events i.e., schedule_once etc.,

In my test code, I'm trying to update label text with schedule_once. For some unknown reason, label text is not updating. but for loop is executing.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial
from time import sleep

kv = '''
Some:
    target: target
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height
        
        Label:
            id: target
            text: 'Text will be changed'
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1, .5
            
        Button:
            text: 'Change'
            on_press: root.click()
'''

class Some(Widget):
    
    target = ObjectProperty(None)

    def click(self):
        
        for i in range(10):
            sleep(1)
            print(i)
            Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: partial(self.update_text, i), 10-i)
            
    def update_text(self, k):
        self.target.text = str(k)

class TestingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)
     
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestingApp().run()
```

Please help me out and tell me how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem, with a couple issues.

- The simplest issue is that you are calling `Clock.schedule_once()` with a `timeout` of "10 - i". That will result in all of the scheduled executions happening at about the same time. Is that what you intended?
- Your `click()` method is running on the main thread, thus holding that thread for the duration of the `for` loop in that method. That prevents any updates to the GUI until the `click()` method returns.
- When you use a `lambda` in a loop, and try to use the loop variable (in your case `i`) in the `lambda`, the `i` variable is not evaluated until the `lambda` is evaluated That evaluation is after the loop completes, so the `i` in your `lambda` will always evaluate to `9`.
- When you use a method in a `lambda`, you must include the `()` after the method name. Odd because everywhere else you would just use the method name.

So, you can change your `Clock.schedule_once()` call to:

```
Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt, j=i: partial(self.update_text, j)(), 10+i)
```

In the above line, the `j=i` creates another argument to the `lambda` that gets evaluated when the `lambda` is created. Also the `()` added to the end of the `partial` as mentioned above.

However, that code still holds the main thread for 10 seconds. If you just want the `Label` updated every second, you don't need to use `sleep` in that loop, just provide the `timeout` argument to `Clock.schedule_once()` that schedules the change as desired. Here is a modified version of your `click()` method that combines everything above:

```
def click(self):
    for i in range(10):
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt, j=i: partial(self.update_text, j)(), i)
```

Using `lambda` and `partial` together can get confusing. Here is another version of your code that uses `Clock.schedule_interval()` instead. To me, this code is easier to follow:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

kv = '''
Some:
    target: target

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            id: target
            text: root.txt
            font_size: 32
            size_hint: 1, .5

        Button:
            text: 'Change'
            on_press: root.click()
'''


class Some(Widget):
    target = ObjectProperty(None)
    txt = StringProperty('Text will be changed')


    def click(self):
        self.current_update = 0
        self.stop_update = 9
        self.clock_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_text, 1)

    def update_text(self, dt):
        self.txt = str(self.current_update)
        self.current_update += 1
        if self.current_update > self.stop_update:
            self.clock_event.cancel()


class TestingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestingApp().run()
```